# How do i make a login form redirect

Tags: html, css, forms, authentication

Guys im new to web development and i made a login form with a username and a password but i dont know how to get it so when the password and the username are correct it takes u to a new html file like this window.location="welcome.html"; can somebody help.
Html: for this i did use a tutorial ik but it doesnt tell u how to setup the username and password system

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="curved-shape"></div>
    <div class="form-box Login">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="text">
          <label for="">Username</label>
          <i class='bx bxs-user'></i>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="text" id="pswd">
          <label for="">Password</label>
          <i class='bx bxs-lock-alt'></i>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <button class="btn" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="info-content Login">
      <h2>WELCOME BACK!</h2>
      <p>This is a site developed by Zechariah Echols!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #25252b;
}
.container{
 position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 2px solid #ff2770;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #ff2770;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .form-box{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.form-box.Login{
  left: 0%;
  padding: 0 40px;
}
.form-box h2{
  position: relative;
  text-allign: center;
}

.form-box .input-box{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.input-box input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding-right: 23px;
  transition: .5s;
}
.input-box input:focus,
.input-box input:focus{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff2770;
}
.input-box label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
}
.input-box input:focus ~ label,
.input-box input:focus ~ label{
  top: -5px;
  color: #ff2770;
}
.input-box i{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: .5s;
}
.input-box input:focus ~ i,
.input-box input:focus ~ i{
  top: -5px;
  color: #ff2770;
}
.btn{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px solid #ff2770;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.btn::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#25252b, #ff2770, #25252b, #ff2770);
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
}
.btn:hover:before{
  top: 0;
}
.info-content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.info-content.Login{
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 40px 60px 150px;
}
.info-content h2{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.info-content p{
  font-size: 16px;
}
.container .curved-shape{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -5px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 850px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#25252b,#ff2770);
  transform: rotate(10deg) skewY(40deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

I’m expecting it to take u to a new html window when the username is pugls and the password is PugWareX

Comment: What does your `script.js` file within `<script src="script.js"></script>` do?

Comment: I dont have a script inside scrip.js i just put the script in the html code itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your script.js file with the following changes:

First, give your inputs an id attribute for easy access through JavaScript:

```
<input type="text" id="usernameInput">
<input type="password" id="passwordInput">
```

Update your JavaScript (script.js) to include the logic for checking the credentials and redirecting:

```
// Select the login form
const loginForm = document.querySelector('.form-box.Login form');

// Add a submit event listener to the form
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally

  // Get the values from the input fields
  const username = document.getElementById('usernameInput').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('passwordInput').value;

  // Check if the credentials are correct
  if (username === 'pugls' && password === 'PugWareX') {
    // Redirect to the welcome page
    window.location.href = 'welcome.html';
  } else {
    alert('Incorrect username or password. Please try again.');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
function handleSubmit(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
   login();
}
function login() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
  const labelElement = document.getElementById("erroe-msg");
    if (username == "admin" && password == "1234") {
      alert("1");
        window.location = "welcome.html";
    } else {
      alert("2");
      labelElement.textContent = "Invalid username or password";
    }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #25252b;
}
.container{
 position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 2px solid #ff2770;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #ff2770;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .form-box{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.form-box.Login{
  left: 0%;
  padding: 0 40px;
}
.form-box h2{
  position: relative;
  text-allign: center;
}

.form-box .input-box{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.input-box input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding-right: 23px;
  transition: .5s;
}
.input-box input:focus,
.input-box input:focus{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff2770;
}
.input-box label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
}
.input-box input:focus ~ label,
.input-box input:focus ~ label{
  top: -5px;
  color: #ff2770;
}
.input-box i{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: .5s;
}
.input-box input:focus ~ i,
.input-box input:focus ~ i{
  top: -5px;
  color: #ff2770;
}
.btn{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px solid #ff2770;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.btn::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#25252b, #ff2770, #25252b, #ff2770);
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
}
.btn:hover:before{
  top: 0;
}
.info-content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.info-content.Login{
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 40px 60px 150px;
}
.info-content h2{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.info-content p{
  font-size: 16px;
}
.container .curved-shape{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -5px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 850px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#25252b,#ff2770);
  transform: rotate(10deg) skewY(40deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="curved-shape"></div>
    <div class="form-box Login">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form id="myForm">
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="text" id="username">
          <label for="">Username</label>
          <i class='bx bxs-user'></i>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="text" id="pswd">
          <label for="">Password</label>
          <i class='bx bxs-lock-alt'></i>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <button class="btn" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <label id="erroe-msg"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="info-content Login">
      <h2>WELCOME BACK!</h2>
      <p>This is a site developed by Arunachalam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not good answers. How does this solve the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).